# Impersonation using a Smartcard login

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, smartcard, impersonation

My .net forms application needs to connect to a database using integrated security. Many of the users are logged in on a shared windows account. I would like them to be able to "log in" in the application and use impersonation to access the database. I have figured out how to do this using a username and password, but my company it getting rid of passwords in favor of smartcard login.

I have tried using X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser) to get the certificate from my smartcard, but I get a bunch of certs and none of them seem to work. I keep getting false from LogonUser with the error message "The user name or password is incorrect"

```
        private void impersonateTest()
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = GetClientCertificate();
            if (cert != null)
            {
                //This method is used to create a username from the selected certificate
                UserLoginInfo user = Login(cert);

                if (user.username != string.Empty)
                {
                    SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
                    try
                    {
                        bool returnValue = LogonUser(user.username, user.domain, textBoxPassword.Text,
                            LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);

                        if (false == returnValue)
                        {
                            int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                            throw new Win32Exception(ret);
                        }
                        using (safeTokenHandle)
                        {
                            using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
                            {
                                using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
                                {
                                    //Query the database using integrated security
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //handle
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate()
        {
            IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
            var x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser); 
            try
            {
                x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
                // Nothing to do if no cert found.
                if (x509Store.Certificates != null && x509Store.Certificates.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (x509Store.Certificates.Count == 1)
                    {
                        // Return the certificate present.
                        certificate = x509Store.Certificates[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Request the user to select a certificate 
                        var certificates = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
                            x509Store.Certificates,
                            "Digital Certificates", "Select a certificate from the following list:",
                            X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection, ptr);
                        
                        // Check if one has been returned
                        if (certificates != null && certificates.Count > 0)
                            certificate = certificates[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                x509Store.Close();
            }

            return certificate;
        }

        public UserLoginInfo Login(X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            UserLoginInfo uli = new UserLoginInfo();
            try
            {
                CERT_CREDENTIAL_INFO certInfo = new CERT_CREDENTIAL_INFO();
                certInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CERT_CREDENTIAL_INFO));

                certInfo.rgbHashOfCert = cert.GetCertHash();

                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(certInfo);
                IntPtr pCertInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(certInfo, pCertInfo, false);

                IntPtr marshaledCredential = IntPtr.Zero;
                bool result = CredMarshalCredential(CertCredential, pCertInfo, out marshaledCredential);

                string userName = string.Empty;
                if (result)
                {
                    userName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(marshaledCredential);
                }

                uli.domain = textBoxDomain.Text; 
                uli.username = userName;
                
                return uli;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return uli;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you created _middleware_ and only the middleware connected to the database and the users would authenticate to the middleware, then you wouldn't have this issue.